# Unity Call Touch Functions on A 3d Text if clicked any where on screen. Instead of clicking on the text only

Tags: android, touch, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity. I am following the car tutorial and trying to port it to Android. Some how I managed to move the car in device. The problem is that I am using a 3D text which will be clicked to accelerate the car. What I did is

Created a 3D Text. Added box collider to it. Check the is Trigger option of Box Collider. Added the following script.

```
 public var Mainref:TouchPlaneScript;

 function FixedUpdate() 
 {

  var touch: Touch = Input.touches[0];

  if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
  {
     Mainref.applyBrake = true;
  }
  if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
  {
     Mainref.applyBrake = false;
  }

}

  function Start () 
  { 
  // Find the OtherScript which is attached to any game object in the scene. 
     Mainref = FindObjectOfType(TouchPlaneScript);
  }

  function OnMouseUp()
  {
    Mainref.applyBrake = false;
    Debug.Log("Stop Brake");
  }
  function OnMouseDown()
  {
    Mainref.applyBrake = true;
    Debug.Log("Apply Brake");
  }
```

The logic inside the Touch Methods might be wrong don't worry about that. I have also commented the code for mouse functions while running it on device. But the problem remains the same.

**THE PROBLEM IS THAT** TOUCH METHODS ARE CALLED IF TOUCHED ON THE SCREEN ANY WHERE I WANT TOUCH FUNCTIONS TO BE CALLED ONLY WHEN CLICKED ON THE TEXT.

Please note that I have four buttons on the scene. left,right,brake,accel all are 3d text and have the same structure and same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code have detect the click event by checking input touches, but you didn't check the position of the target, so once you click on the screen, every thing happens. You need to check the position of the touch to make sure you are doing the right operation. Code below(not familiar with JS, this is C# version, you need to translate it on your own):

```
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if ( Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer ||
        Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android )
    {
        if ( Input.touchCount <= 0 )
            return;

        // detect single touch only
        Touch touch  = Input.touches[0];

        if ( touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began )
        {
            Debug.Log( 123 );
            OnTouchBegan( touch.position );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown( 0 ) )
        {
            Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition);
            OnTouchBegan( Input.mousePosition );
        }
    }
}

    void OnTouchBegan (Vector2 screenPos)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay( screenPos );
        RaycastHit hit;

        if ( Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit ) )
        {
            hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("OnClick", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        }
    }
```

after this, you need to create a new script implementing a method OnClick() and attach it on your 3D text game object. Then your 3D text will receive the OnClick message when you click on it.

Hope this helps.

By the way, if there is more than one camera in your scene, you need to change Camera.main to the camera which sees the 3D text.

Comment: where to attach the above script? Should I attach it to a 3D text or somewhere else?

Comment: the above code is not working :( The condition in if statement is not running :( Please help

Comment: you have to attach this script list above somewhere else, and make sure there is only one instance in your scene.

Comment: about the not working problem: I think you are testing this on your computer, not on your mobile devices; so the problem is, there is no Touch input on computer, you have to detect the mouse click event. I will edit the answer above.

Comment: remember to create a NEW script which contains a function void OnClick(), and attach this script to every 3D text which has a box collider attached. Then the OnClick Function will be invoked if you click on the 3D text, and by the way, if you have more than one 3D text and you need them to respond in different way, you need more than one scipt with OnClick function and attach them to different 3D text. for more info, i think you should try to read the Unity script reference by searching: 1. Input 2. SendMessage 3. Raycast; and wish you have a good day and sorry for the delay of the reply

Comment: I am trying it on a device. Should I attached the above script to the plane? Because I have only 2 objects one is 3d Text and other is Plane. But plane is behind 3D text. Will it work in that case?

Comment: you have to add a camera to your scene, otherwise the ray cast will not work, and tag your camera as MainCamera. you can create a new GameObject and attach the script to it, or just attach it to the camera.

Comment: Finally I am unable to get it working. Now a tiny miny another question. Suppose I have two buttons now, how can I differentiate which object is touched?

Comment: No, it will work if you do this, but you have to name all your buttons differently. remember I told you to create a new script with a function OnClick()? you can create more than one of this, such as OpenPage.cs, ClosePage.cs, StartGame.cs, and then attach one of them to each of your buttons, then your buttons will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Raycast in Unity, to make sure that the 3D text is well touched.

You can check the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Input.html) at the section "Mobile input"

Comment: I cant find any solution to my problem there. Can you please help with a piece of code?